# IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist when call to SimpleCursorAdaptor

Tags: android, database

I have a table named "master" with columns `id`, `name`, `surname`, `gender`, and  `designation`

When I fire off a query to get a [Cursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) object for a [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) I get:

```
IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist when call to CursorAdaptor
```

But I don't have a columen named "_id".

Can anybody tell me why I am getting this error?

Here is the stack trace:

```
07-13 15:45:40.582: WARN/System.err(295): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
07-13 15:45:40.592: WARN/System.err(295):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:314)
07-13 15:45:40.592: WARN/System.err(295):     at android.widget.CursorAdapter.changeCursor(CursorAdapter.java:257)
07-13 15:45:40.602: WARN/System.err(295):     at com.praumtech.names4baby.ui.NamesListAdapter.setCursor(NamesListAdapter.java:63)
07-13 15:45:40.602: WARN/System.err(295):     at com.praumtech.names4baby.ui.BoysNamesListActivity.initNameList(BoysNamesListActivity.java:79)
07-13 15:45:40.602: WARN/System.err(295):     at com.praumtech.names4baby.ui.BoysNamesListActivity.onCreate(BoysNamesListActivity.java:49)
07-13 15:45:40.602: WARN/System.err(295):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
07-13 15:45:40.602: WARN/System.err(295):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
07-13 15:45:40.612: WARN/System.err(295):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
07-13 15:45:40.612: WARN/System.err(295):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:116)
07-13 15:45:40.612: WARN/System.err(295):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
07-13 15:45:40.612: WARN/System.err(295):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-13 15:45:40.621: WARN/System.err(295):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-13 15:45:40.621: WARN/System.err(295):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
07-13 15:45:40.621: WARN/System.err(295):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-13 15:45:40.621: WARN/System.err(295):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-13 15:45:40.621: WARN/System.err(295):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
07-13 15:45:40.621: WARN/System.err(295):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
07-13 15:45:40.631: WARN/System.err(295):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is happening because `CursorAdapter` must have an `_id` column in the table it is using.

With the Database(SQLite) in Android applications, it is better to add a column named _id" to all tables in order to be able to use `CursorAdapter`.

Alternatively, you can write an sql statement like

```
select member_id as _id from member _table where ....."
```

in order to get a `Cursor` which may be used with `CursorAdapter`.

This is specified in `CursorAdaptor`'s [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html):

> Adapter that exposes data from a Cursor to a ListView widget. The
>   Cursor must include a column named "_id" or this class will not work."

Answer (score 1):

Your `namemaster` tables needs to have a column `_ID` defined to be used by SimpleCursorAdaptor. Make sure your table schema includes `_ID` and not an `id` as the later is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Simple and Salty

To overcome this problem, you have to rename the primary key field name as `_id`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the SimpleCursorAdapter assumes that there is a column '_id'. You need to create it so it would probably be easier for you to use "_id" instead of your own "id".
Read the 2nd post on this [page](http://www.anddev.org/column__id_doesnt_exist-t12189.html)