# android sqlite exception:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist

Tags: android, sqlite

I created a sql lite database with the following columns:

```
static final String dbName="demoDB";
    static final String tableName="Employees";
    static final String colID="EmployeeID";
```

then

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+tableName+" ("+colID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
                colName+" TEXT, "+colAge+" Integer);");
    }
```

I want to select all the records in the database like this and display them in a gridview:

```
SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
         Cursor cur= db.rawQuery("Select "+colName+", "+colAge+" from "+tableName, new String [] {});

String [] from=new String []{DatabaseHelper.colName,DatabaseHelper.colAge};
            int [] to=new int [] {R.id.colName,R.id.colAge};
            SimpleCursorAdapter sca=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.gridrow,c,from,to);


        GridView grid=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid);
        grid.setAdapter(sca);
```

but i receive the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist.
```

the db table does not have a column with name '_id'

so what is wrong with this code

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [ IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist when call to SimpleCursorAdaptor ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236203/illegalargumentexception-column-id-does-not-exist-when-call-to-simplecursora)

Comment: Just because the other thread doesn't provide an answer doesn't mean this one isn't a duplicate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

a workaround to this problem is to use select statment like this

**select EmpId as _id**

cause the adapter requires a column with the name _id as you said

thanks

Answer (score 4):

When using an adapter, your Table must always have the Primary Key Column named as "`_id`"

Just change

```
static final String colID="EmployeeID";
```

to

```
static final String colID="_id";
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

[CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html)s require an `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` column named `_id` (available from [BaseColumns](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/provider/BaseColumns.html)).

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
SELECT  _ID as _ID,_ID as _id , cont_type ,.... FROM  DATABASE_TABLE ;

When _ID only ,Message is column '_id' does not exist.
When _id only ,Message is column '_ID' does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried _id (lower case) instead of _ID (Uppercase) solves the problem. Make sure to recreate the DB once again with _id (lowercase)

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If you loading your database from assets: After you have changde your id to _id in the database base table, and your loading it from assets folder that you uninstall the app first, otherwise you will be using your old database.