# Using ListView in CustomAlertDialog Layout

Tags: android

I'm using the following code to use a `ListView` in `CustomAlertDialog Layout`.

```
public void onButtonClicked(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(this,
            Messages.getString("OSListActivity.195"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //$NON-NLS-1$
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.buttondialog, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setView(view);
    ListView mbListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.mblist);
    builder.setTitle(Messages.getString("OSListActivity.196"))
            .setNeutralButton(Messages.getString("OSListActivity.197"),
                    null);
    MatrixCursor dcursor = propmanager.propCursor();
    if (dcursor.moveToFirst()) {
        startManagingCursor(dcursor);
        String[] from = { "name", "value" };
        int[] to = { R.id.mbname, R.id.mbvalue };
        SimpleCursorAdapter dadapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.mblistrow, dcursor, from, to);
        mbListView.setAdapter(dadapter);
    }
    builder.show(); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$
}
```

However I'm getting the following error. Why? What am I doing wrong here?

```
03-30 18:45:50.867: E/AndroidRuntime(11170):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
03-30 18:45:50.867: E/AndroidRuntime(11170):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
03-30 18:45:50.867: E/AndroidRuntime(11170):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-30 18:45:50.867: E/AndroidRuntime(11170):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-30 18:45:50.867: E/AndroidRuntime(11170):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-30 18:45:50.867: E/AndroidRuntime(11170):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-30 18:45:50.867: E/AndroidRuntime(11170):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-30 18:45:50.867: E/AndroidRuntime(11170):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-30 18:45:50.867: E/AndroidRuntime(11170):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-30 18:45:50.867: E/AndroidRuntime(11170):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-30 18:45:50.867: E/AndroidRuntime(11170): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-30 18:45:50.867: E/AndroidRuntime(11170):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-30 18:45:50.867: E/AndroidRuntime(11170):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-30 18:45:50.867: E/AndroidRuntime(11170):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3039)
03-30 18:45:50.867: E/AndroidRuntime(11170):    ... 11 more
03-30 18:45:50.867: E/AndroidRuntime(11170): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
03-30 18:45:50.867: E/AndroidRuntime(11170):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:267)
03-30 18:45:50.867: E/AndroidRuntime(11170):    at android.widget.CursorAdapter.init(CursorAdapter.java:168)
03-30 18:45:50.867: E/AndroidRuntime(11170):    at android.widget.CursorAdapter.<init>(CursorAdapter.java:116)
03-30 18:45:50.867: E/AndroidRuntime(11170):    at android.widget.ResourceCursorAdapter.<init>(ResourceCursorAdapter.java:52)
03-30 18:45:50.867: E/AndroidRuntime(11170):    at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.<init>(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:78)
03-30 18:45:50.867: E/AndroidRuntime(11170):    at com.manager.boot.free.MultiBootManager.onButtonClicked(MultiBootManager.java:103)
03-30 18:45:50.867: E/AndroidRuntime(11170):    ... 14 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use a cursor that **requires** a column called **_id**. Add a column (**_id**) in your table or include your primary key column in query as (**yourColumn AS _id**) to fix this issue. For [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244472/android-sqlite-exceptionjava-lang-illegalargumentexception-column-id-does-n)