# column '_id' does not exist **Error**

Tags: android, sqlite

DB handel

```
package sh.mkt;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;

public class handle extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public static final String SHARE_MKT_DB = "SHARE_DB";
    public static final String COMPANY_TABLE = "COMPANY_NAME";
    public static final String SHARE_TABLE = "SHARE_DETAIL";
    public static final int MYDATABASE_VERSION = 3;
    public static final String TAB_ID = "_id";
    public static final String TAB_ID2 = "_id2";
    public static final String COMPANY_NAME = "Company";
    public static final String SHARE_PRICE= "Shareprice";
    public static final String SHARE_VOLUME = "Sharevolume";

    public handle(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
            int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          db.execSQL(SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE);
           db.execSQL(SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + COMPANY_TABLE);
              db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + SHARE_TABLE);
              onCreate(db);
    }

    private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE = "create table " + COMPANY_TABLE + " (" 
                +TAB_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
                + COMPANY_NAME + " text not null);";

    private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE2 = "create table " + SHARE_TABLE + " (" 
                + TAB_ID2 + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
                + SHARE_PRICE + " text not null, " 
                + SHARE_VOLUME + " text not null, "
                + " FOREIGN KEY ("+TAB_ID2+") REFERENCES "+COMPANY_TABLE+" ("+TAB_ID+"));";
}
```

Activity

```
    package sh.mkt;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class next extends Activity {

    TextView a;
    Button back;
    ListView list;

    ListView listContent;
    private handle hand;
    Cursor cursor;
    SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter;
    private SQLiteDatabase dbObject;

    private static final String fields[] = { handle.TAB_ID2 , handle.SHARE_PRICE , handle.SHARE_VOLUME };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);

        a = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView123);
        back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backb);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contentlist3);


//      Company obj1 = new Company();
//      String val1 = obj1.getCompanyID();

        hand = new handle(getApplicationContext(),
                handle.SHARE_MKT_DB, null,
                handle.MYDATABASE_VERSION);

        dbObject = hand.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor data = dbObject.query(handle.SHARE_TABLE, fields, null, null, null, null, null);

        String[] from = new String[]{handle.SHARE_PRICE};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text2, R.id.text3};
        cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row2, data, from, to);
        listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);


        back.setOnClickListener(backlistner);

    }

    Button.OnClickListener backlistner = new Button.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent(
                    "android.intent.action.ShareMarketActivity"));

        }

    };
}
```

**_id does not exist**

> 10-05 16:27:01.268: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16525): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   10-05 16:27:01.268: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16525):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{sh.mkt/sh.mkt.next}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   column '_id' does not exist 10-05 16:27:01.268:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16525):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
>   10-05 16:27:01.268: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16525):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
>   10-05 16:27:01.268: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16525):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125) 10-05
>   16:27:01.268: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16525):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
>   10-05 16:27:01.268: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16525):     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 10-05
>   16:27:01.268: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16525):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 10-05 16:27:01.268:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16525):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) 10-05
>   16:27:01.268: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16525):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 10-05
>   16:27:01.268: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16525):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 10-05 16:27:01.268:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16525):     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   10-05 16:27:01.268: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16525):     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626) 10-05
>   16:27:01.268: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16525):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 10-05 16:27:01.268:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16525): Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist 10-05
>   16:27:01.268: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16525):     at
>   android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:314)
>   10-05 16:27:01.268: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16525):     at
>   android.widget.CursorAdapter.init(CursorAdapter.java:111) 10-05
>   16:27:01.268: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16525):     at
>   android.widget.CursorAdapter.(CursorAdapter.java:90) 10-05
>   16:27:01.268: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16525):     at
>   android.widget.ResourceCursorAdapter.(ResourceCursorAdapter.java:47)
>   10-05 16:27:01.268: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16525):     at
>   android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:84)
>   10-05 16:27:01.268: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16525):     at
>   sh.mkt.next.onCreate(next.java:52) 10-05 16:27:01.268:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16525):     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   10-05 16:27:01.268: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16525):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)

hey again sorry to disturb again... but it did not worked... it showd as it worked but actually it did not.

Comment: change fields to `fields[] = {` **handle.KEY_ID** `, handle.SHARE_PRICE, handle.SHARE_VOLUME};`

Comment: thank you verymuch Selvin... you a r a life savor :) it worked

Comment: hey again sorry to disturb again... but it did not worked... it showd as it worked but actually it did not.

Answer (score 3):

I think that your fields selection:

```
private static final String fields[] = {handle.SHARE_PRICE, handle.SHARE_VOLUME};
```

should be

```
private static final String fields[] = {handle.KEY_ID, handle.SHARE_PRICE, handle.SHARE_VOLUME};
```

Because the cursor Adapter needs a cursor that have '_id' column in it to identify its row. Anyway I always use [BaseColumns](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/BaseColumns.html) to help me out with the annoying '_id' column.

Comment: hey again sorry to disturb again... but it did not worked... it showd as it worked but actually it did not.

Comment: LockWhick you are setting TAB_ID2 which contains the value of'_id2' you MUST set it to TAB_ID2 to '_id' otherwise it will not work

Answer (score 1):

you can find your happyness easily via a simple search , refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=column%20%27_id%27%20does%20not%20exist%20)

Comment: yes i tried... but still i could not understand what i have done wrong. if you can direct me i would be very gratefull....

Comment: add a space between the "(" and the KEY_ID .. and try it

Comment: + COMPANY_TABLE + " ( " + KEY_ID2 + " integer primary key autoincrement, " this way>????

Comment: hey again sorry to disturb again... but it did not worked... it showd as it worked but actually it did not.

Comment: refer this question to understand it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236203/illegalargumentexception-column-id-does-not-exist-when-call-to-simplecursorad

Comment: yes but in my case 1 table COMPANY_TABLE is having the primary key _id
but there is a second table SHARE_TABLE with a forign key refers to primary key of COMPANY_TABLE. as you says i have to change _id2 also as _id?

Comment: yes, change it to _id , and declare it as a Foreign key , this is no problem if you named it _id , try it and tell me what the result is

Comment: yes now it got solved.... thank you Houcine... well there is an after problem that occurs.

10-06 11:14:29.719: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(273): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{sh.mkt/sh.mkt.next}: java.lang.NullPointerException

but the database has values already.

Comment: glad to hear it , the second problem i think you should declare you activity on your manifest file :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you increment your `handle.MYDATABASE_VERSION` ?

To check if this is an upgrade problem uninstall your application and reinstall it. If you don't have any issue afterwards, you should check your upgrade code.

Comment: i did so but still the problem is the same